# "Locust command not found" returns even after I have installed Locust on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, locust

I have installed locust using the pip command and when I move forward towards verifying the installation using this command: **locust -v** , it throws the following line back: **Command Not Found**

Secondly, when I installed Locust, some statements showed up on console as can be seen in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message in yellow is the problem. Add that directory to your PATH variable.

`export PATH=/home/purelogics/.local/bin:$PATH`

After updating path, `locust -V` will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem. I am using linux for the first time and have no idea how to add that specific directory to the PATH variable...Any thoughts?

Comment: You’re welcome! Have a look at https://stackabuse.com/how-to-permanently-set-path-in-linux/ for example

Comment: Thanks, let me try this one out :)